# Intsall MS R Client without internet connection

Tags: r

I'm trying to install MS R Client on a Windows 2012 server machine that is not connected to the Internet and the installation process fails.

In the prerequisistes for this product specifyied that Intenet connection is required.

So, is there any way of how to intsall MS R Client on the machine without internet connection?

Comment: sounds like a support question to Microsoft.

Comment: yes, MS specifies that Internet connection is required in order to install R Client, so I'm changing my question to reflect my understanging of that fact....

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695942.aspx ?

Comment: It's not exactly the same I'm talking about unfortunately. I need help regarding [R Client] product.

Comment: did you try to do an offline install? it worked fine for me (I downloaded the installer & disabled all network interfaces before running it). The only thing you don't get are the packages it would have installed if there was an internet connection.

Comment: Yes, I tried to install it offline. Your experience seems a little strange for me as R Client has MRO as a dependency and it's not clear how it manages to download and install it offline.